# Incoherence in DSCAL between MKL BLAS and Accelerate Framework BLAS in OSX

Tags: macos, ieee-754, blas, intel-mkl, accelerate-framework

Under OSX with the OSX BLAS (Accelerate Framework). The following program

```
  real*8 :: x(2)
  real*8 :: zero=0.0d0
  x(1)=1.0d0
  x(2)=1/zero
  print*, x(2)*0.0d0
  call dscal(2,0.d0,x,1)
  print*, x
  end
```

gives me the following output

```
                   NaN
0.0000000000000000        0.0000000000000000
```

and the following output on OSX+MKL BLAS

```
                   NaN
0.0000000000000000                            NaN
```

i.e. it seems that the OSX BLAS DSCAL makes a short-circuit in the multiplication by 0 (we got X(2)=0 although 0*Inf=NaN should be obtained)

Is it a known bug/feature ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is neither a bug nor a feature. It is in the discretion of the implementer what the result of `0*NaN` `0*Inf` is. What is the purpose of the above anyway?

Comment: The Scilab software (www.scilab.org) replaces the reference BLAS with MKL BLAS during installation on Windows platform. Under Linux the reference BLAS is used and under OSX the Accelerate Framework BLAS is used. Hence we obtain different results on different platforms in these limit cases. This is a problem. Does there exist a BLAS function giving the BLAS vendor ?

Comment: Kind of. You can use infrastructure like CMake's `FindBLAS.cmake` and `FindLapack.cmake` to understand, what implementation you are dealing with, while building your own code. I do that to some extent here: https://github.com/kvahed/codeare. And there are individual commands that are found only in individual implementations, you could test for. So you would find `mkl_malloc` only when compiling with MKL etc. But the is no `version` command or so that would tell you all.